# How reliable is php function get_browser?

Tags: php, browser, statistics, web-traffic, visitor-statistic

I am trying to find a good way to detect a visitor OS, browser, etc.

I found the PHP function [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

And I see that function can detect Java, I though the function used the user agent for detection, and I don't see any mention to Java on my VMs ua with java installed.

How does the function knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as accurate as your `browscap.ini` file is. The file isn't bundled with PHP so it's up to you to keep it up-to-date. You can get it from http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp.

**Notice**: The values contained in the array are based on the "technical capabilities" of the browser and do not account for features that were disabled by the user (i.e. the user may have disabled JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: It also depends on the useragent that the browser submits.

Answer (score 0):

It is not reliable. It only tells you what the browser might support if it had the feature enabled.

Not to mention, the user agent can be spoofed.